# RLS Policy for a table based on another table

Tags: postgresql, supabase

And based on what I learned, setting an RLS should be easy. But somehow I couldn't make this work. Please shed some light. Thanks.

For table `student`, my policy is as this:

```
    CREATE POLICY "crud" ON "public"."student"
AS PERMISSIVE FOR ALL
TO public
USING ((id IN ( SELECT sb.student_id FROM student_branch sb WHERE (sb.branch_id = ( SELECT a.branch_id FROM admin a WHERE (a.id = '62bfcd1c-016c-416a-a155-388e766b411f'::uuid))))))
WITH CHECK ((id IN ( SELECT sb.student_id FROM student_branch sb WHERE (sb.branch_id = ( SELECT a.branch_id FROM admin a WHERE (a.id = '62bfcd1c-016c-416a-a155-388e766b411f'::uuid))))))
```

which basically an admin with id `62bfcd1c-016c-416a-a155-388e766b411f` which belong to, let say `branch_id = 1` should see only student for `branch_id = 1` in table `student_branch`,

But I get empty result. I tried running sql statement below, it works ok but the policy did not get enforced.

```
select * from student where (id IN ( SELECT sb.student_id
       FROM student_branch sb
      WHERE (sb.branch_id = ( SELECT admin.branch_id
               FROM admin
              WHERE (admin.id = '62bfcd1c-016c-416a-a155-388e766b411f'::uuid)))))
```

the student data

```
id, name
========
1, Student 1
2, Student 2
```

the admin data

```
id, name, branch_id
============
62bfcd1c-016c-416a-a155-388e766b411f, Admin 1, 1
```

the student_branch data

```
id, student_id, branch_id
======================
1, 1, 1
```

access using Supabase API:

```
<url>/student?select=*
```

Comment: Incomplete information. We need the complete `CREATE POLICY` statement, the exact query and the exact definition of the role who runs the query. And ideally some sample data to reproduce what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It seems I've to correctly configure policy for the other table that I'm referring to: `student_branch` and `admin`.

Right now I'm using this policy for those two tables:

```
CREATE POLICY "policy_name"
ON public.student_branch
FOR SELECT USING (
  true
);
```

which I fear is too open which I plan to ask in another new question.